# Re-implementation of Caolan McMahon's parallel and map functions

Tags: beginner, clojure

I have wrote my first reasonably complete piece of ClojureScript code and would like feedback. It is basically a re-implementation of Caolan McMahon's [parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) and
[map](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) functions from [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) in ClojureScript.

This may be a completely useless exercise because Library X already does this or Feature Y of ClojureScript is a more sensible way to go and I would like to know about these libraries or features of ClojureScript but I would also like tips on how this code can be improved as my experience with ClojureScript is very limited.

#### src/cljs-async/async.cljs

```
(ns cljs-async.async)


(defn- map-many-results-to-fire-next-callbacks [next-callbacks results]
  (let [all-errs (map first results)
        real-errs (filter #(not (= 0 %)) all-errs)
        err-caller #(% (first real-errs) nil)
        success-caller #(% (first all-errs) (vec (map second results)))
        caller (if (empty? real-errs) success-caller err-caller)
        ]
    (loop [fst (first next-callbacks) rst (rest next-callbacks)]
      (caller fst)
      (if (= 0 (count rst))
        nil
        (recur (first rst) (rest rst))))))

(defn ^:export async-parallel [inputs output]
  (let [res (atom (vec (repeat (count inputs) nil))) ; Atom to collect results.
        nodejs-callback (fn [pos err result] ; Will put the callback result in the correct place in
                          ; the `res` atom then if the `res` atom has no nils
                          ; left in it will call the
                          ; `map-many-results-to-fire-next-callbacks` which will
                          ; despatch the final answer to output.
                          (swap! res assoc pos [err result])
                          (if (empty? (filter nil? @res))
                            (map-many-results-to-fire-next-callbacks [output] @res)
                            ))
        nodejs-fire (fn [pos] ; Fires a function in `inputs` (denoted by `pos`) registering the
                      ; `nodejs-callback` function to collect the result (in the right spot)
                      ((inputs pos) (partial nodejs-callback pos)))
        ]
    (loop [f (first inputs) r (rest inputs) pos 0] ; Loop around the inputs and fire the callbacks
      (nodejs-fire pos)
      (if (= 0 (count r))
        nil
        (recur (first r) (rest r) (inc pos))))))

(defn ^:export async-map [pred args next-callback]
  (let [inputs (vec (map #(partial pred %) args))
        cb (fn [ e xs ]
             (if (= 0 e)
               (next-callback e xs)
               (next-callback e nil)))
        ]
    (async-parallel inputs cb)))
```

#### src/cljs-async/test.cljs

```
(ns cljs-nodejs-coreasync-bootstrap.test
  (:require
    [cljs.nodejs :as nodejs]
    [cljs-nodejs-coreasync-bootstrap.async :as callback-async]))

(def node-like-cb-func (nodejs/require "./asyncThing.js"))

(defn test-is-equal [expected async-func-missing-callback message]
  (async-func-missing-callback (fn [err result]
                                 (print (str
                                          message "\n\t"
                                          expected "\n\t"
                                          [err result] "\n\n\n")))))


(defn -main [& args]

  (test-is-equal [0 [2 3 4]]
                 (partial callback-async/async-map node-like-cb-func [1 2 3])
                 "Standard map")

  (test-is-equal [0 [2 3 11]]
                 (partial callback-async/async-map node-like-cb-func [1 2 10])
                 "Edge case map")

  (test-is-equal [1 nil]
                 (partial callback-async/async-map node-like-cb-func [1 2 11])
                 "Node Err with map")

  (test-is-equal [0 [2 3 4]]
                 (partial callback-async/async-parallel
                          [(partial node-like-cb-func 1) (partial node-like-cb-func 2) (partial node-like-cb-func 3)]
                          )
                 "Standard parallel")
  (test-is-equal [1 nil]
                 (partial callback-async/async-parallel
                          [(partial node-like-cb-func 1) (partial node-like-cb-func 2) (partial node-like-cb-func 11)]
                          )
                 "Err parallel")
  )

(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)
```

#### asyncThing.js

```
'use strict'

module.exports = function getCheese(x, resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (x > 10) {
            return resolve(1);
        }
        resolve(0, (1 + x));
    }, (Math.random() * 100) + 100);
};
```